# Trouble Displaying Query Results in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am creating a flight booker in Rails and I'm having trouble showing my flight information for eligible flights on rails. The user can select to and from airports, passengers, and a date for the flight. If the flight exists it displays the information. But my flight isn't displaying.

index.html form to display the flights

```
  <p>
  <% unless @eligible_flights.empty? %>
        <% @eligible_flights.each do |f| %>
          <%= f.start_airport_id %>
        <% end %>
  <% else %>
        <%= "No Flights Found" %>
  <% end %>
  </p>
```

flights controller to view

```
  def index
    @flights = Flight.all
    @eligible_flights = Flight.where("start_airport_id = ? AND end_airport_id = ? AND departure_time = ?", 
                                        params[:start_airport],
                                        params[:end_airport],
                                        params[:departure_time])
  end
```

Comment: So, it's saying "No flights found"? Are you sure you have data in your database? Most likely you need to do that or fix your query.

Comment: If you're fetching `Flight.all` the line before, just use a `@flights.select` afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that the date comparison is not working correctly, you should try implementing your query the Rails way with.

```
@eligible_flights = Flight
                     .where(start_airport_id: params[:start_airport])
                     .where(end_airport_id: params[:end_airport])
                     .where(departure_time: params[:departure_time])
```